# How to subtract float values in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script which uses float values but some how i am not able to subtract two floats.

This is the sample code

```
#!/bin/bash

p="1"
h="10"
m=$(echo "3.5"| bc -l)
for (( c=$p; c<=$h; c++ ))
do
   r=$(echo "($p-$m)"| bc -l)

   echo "Z $c $m $r"
done
```

and this is the result

```
Z 1 3.5 -2.5
Z 2 3.5 -2.5
Z 3 3.5 -2.5
Z 4 3.5 -2.5
Z 5 3.5 -2.5
Z 6 3.5 -2.5
Z 7 3.5 -2.5
Z 8 3.5 -2.5
Z 9 3.5 -2.5
Z 10 3.5 -2.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
   r=$(echo "($p-$m)"| bc -l)
```

to

```
   r=$(echo "($c-$m)"| bc -l)
```

as it isn't `$p` but `$c` that is changed by the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` doesn't support floating point arithmetic. `ksh` and `zsh` do. POSIXLy, you could use either `bc` as [Florian's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/646022/295286) suggests, or `awk`. For instance,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 2.5+3.7}'
6.2
```

Ubuntu also comes with `Python` and `Perl` which are more than capable of performing floating point calculations.

```
$ perl -le 'print(2.5+3.7)'
6.2

$ python3 -c 'print(2.5+3.7)'
6.2
```

See also a very extensive list of other options: [How to do integer & float calculations, in bash or other languages/frameworks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40786/85039)

Note also that according to [POSIX Shell Language standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04) in arithmetic expansion `$((...))`:

> Only signed long integer arithmetic is required...As an extension, the shell may recognize arithmetic expressions beyond those listed.

So omission of floating point arithmetic from `bash` and `/bin/dash` is in accordance with POSIX specs.

Comment: It should also be noted that Python is itself excellent as a language for writing entire scripts in. It has all sorts of libraries to do powerful things that are very difficult in shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late but as the result appeared on Google, someone might read this. The solution is to write it as "$a- $b". The space makes it work for me.